# How can I send a GET request using this format JAVA

Tags: java, xml, http, get

I am trying to make a GET request for obtaining a XML document returned as string from a bank connection, but I have tried many examples and all I get is errors.

HTTP GET

The following is a sample HTTP GET request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
GET /indicadoreseconomicos/WebServices/wsIndicadoresEconomicos.asmx/ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicosXML?tcIndicador=string&tcFechaInicio=string&tcFechaFinal=string&tcNombre=string&tnSubNiveles=string HTTP/1.1

Host: indicadoreseconomicos.bccr.fi.cr
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://ws.sdde.bccr.fi.cr">string</string>
```

I replace the parameters as neccessary, but no luck.
I've taken the information from:
http://www.bccr.fi.cr/indicadores_economicos_/ServicioWeb.html

Code I have tried.

```
public String requestRate() {
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").format(new Date());
        String response = "";

        Socket socket = new Socket(defaultURL, 8080);
        String request = "GET /indicadoreseconomicos/WebServices/wsIndicadoresEconomicos.asmx/"
                + "ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicosXML?tcIndicador="
                + tcIndicador+ "&tcFechaInicio="
                + date + "&tcFechaFinal="
                + date + "&tcNombre=user&tnSubNiveles=N HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            os.write(request.getBytes());
            os.flush();

        InputStream is;
            is = socket.getInputStream();
        int ch;
            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
              response += (char) ch;
            socket.close();


        return response;
    }
private String defaultURL = "http://www.indicadoreseconomicos.bccr.fi.cr";
```

I have removed try-catch blocks for easy reading.

Comment: can u share your code please

Comment: Not sure what you're using to issue the GET request, but [HttpClient from Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) is pretty standard in Java.

Comment: I understand, but I have to make it without external libraries.

Comment: Are you sure you need a *GET* request with a payload?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, this code worked for me once:

```
    Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 80);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    dos.write("GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n".getBytes());
    dos.flush();
```

This could be a way if I understand well your question.